# Reply of “thanks for appreciation”

Tags: word-usage

Can I reply “Glad to hear it” to the email saying -“ thanks for appreciation”

He is appreciating my encouragement towards his written story.

Comment: You have not given enough context. Why did the person write "thanks for appreciation”? What do they mean?

Comment: @greybeard- now edited ques

Comment: No, you cannot (or rather **should not**) because, **in this context**, “Glad to hear it” sounds rude and arrogant: the phrase carries the meaning of "I did not expect you to behave correctly, but thanking me is the correct thing to do."

Comment: A simple reply would be "Keep up the good work".

Comment: I agree with @Greybeard. Another possible reply could be "My pleasure".

Comment: THANKS ALL!!!!!